# How do I fadeOut the text of the button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have the following button that I'd like to fadeOut the text. I don't want to fadeout the button, just the text within it. How would I do this?

jQuery So far:

```
$('#name').click(function(){
    //Fade out text
   });
```

Markup:

```
 <button id="name" type="submit" class="btn btn-large">Next >></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to change the color of the text to the color of your button...

```
$('#name').click(function(){
   $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

because fade out a text is not possible...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using twitter bootstrap. In that case, use `<a>` instead of `<button>`

Something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="name" class="btn btn-large"><span id="fade">Next</span></a>
```

then you can just fadeout the span:

```
$("#fade").fadeOut("slow")
```

jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1392/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate a color change from the original color to "transparent".

#### HTML

```
<button id="submit_button">Next >></button>
```

#### CSS

```
#submit_button {
    color: #000;
}
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_button').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color: 'transparent'    
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle as an illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/5p2cH/3/